# How to go through laravel 5.3 to laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

how to downgrade laravel 5.3 to laravel 5.2?

Because the host server uses except php version 5.6.3 but laravel 5.3 utlise laravel 5.6.4?

Answer (score 0):

You can update you `composer.json` file to use version 5.2.
Then delete the vendor directory and run `composer install` again.

Check if everything works fine, because can be some incompatibilities.